# How to use psubscribe with redis gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I use redis-rb and sidekiq. The regular $subscribe method works well but I have no response when using $psubscribe like below:

ActiveJob snipped:

```
$redis = Redis.new(:timeout => 0, :driver => :hiredis)

$redis.psubscribe(".*") do |on|
  on.message do |channel, msg|
    puts msg
  end
end
```

redis-cli comand:
    publish 'abc' 'hello'

also when I tried the example from test file it didnt work.
https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/98e3e7a516fc9b4609bc8ab482605f835a4de621/test/publish_subscribe_test.rb
do you have any suggestions what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using the global variable `$redis` here?

Comment: I am new to rails and dont yet know the $variable convention. I will research it but dont think this is the problem because very similar code works  for redis.subscribe method

Comment: No problem with being new! Just be aware that global variables can lead to a whole world of trouble and should be avoided unless there's no other option. Coming from a PHP or Perl background you might not realize the significance of the `$` in your variable name.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the pmessage method instead of message to receive the message event.

```
$redis.psubscribe(".*") do |on|
  on.pmessage do |pattern, channel, msg|
    puts msg
  end
end
```

See 
https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/98e3e7a516fc9b4609bc8ab482605f835a4de621/test/publish_subscribe_test.rb#L62